# Gmail api php reply and include original attachments

Tags: php, google-api, gmail-api

I am trying to send a "reply" message using Gmails API and PHP. I can send the message, and even upload documents to send with the message, but I can find ZERO articles, docs, zip, nothing on how to reply to a message using Gmails API and including the original documents. If you have any suggestions, please advise. Here is my current code:

```
                    $gMail = new \Google_Service_Gmail($googleClient);
                    $msg = new \Google_Service_Gmail_Message();
                    $msg->setThreadId($threadId);
                    $messageObj = $gMail->users_messages->send("me", $msg);
```

There is a ton of code as well that I have not included because it doesn't need to be. Best case, if anyone could point me to the docs that explain how to attach original files (without having to download them and re-upload them to the email), this would be great.

Thanks.

Comment: There are two ways to send email using the Gmail API ([`messages.send`](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/send) and [`drafts.send`](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/drafts/send)). Both method supports an /upload URI. Also take note that the uploaded media must have these cahracteristics (Maximum file size: 35MB and Accepted Media MIME types: message/rfc822).

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I don't need to know how to upload documents: "I can send the message, and even upload documents to send with the message, but I can find ZERO articles, docs, zip, nothing on how to reply to a message using Gmails API and including the original documents."